# How to test if con-infection between microbes is correlated?

Tags: machine-learning, hypothesis-testing, intraclass-correlation, association-measure

I am analyzing the results from a diagnostic test that looks for the presence of micro-organisms in humans. In some cases, there is only one microbe but in others, there are multiple infections.

What is the statistical test I should apply to assess whether certain microbes are more likely to come up together?

In other words: If I have the species A, B, C, D, E, how can I test if species B and E are more likely to be found together?

Also, what machine learning approach would be best to support the statistical test? That is: what model would be best to investigate this sort of associations?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many possible ways to perform such analysis. I like to think a lot comes from the field of ecology.

One simple way to see if two species co-occurs more frequently or less frequently than what would be expected by chance alone, is the coefficient of association of Forbes.

If there are n independent samples (individuals).

If specie A occurs in a samples.

If specie B occurs in b samples.

Then species A and B would be expected, under the null hypothesis of no association, to co-occur in proportion a*b/n samples.

Then comes your observation that A and B actually co-occur in m samples. So in proportion h = m/n of samples.

Then if h > (a*b/n) , or equivalently if h/(a*b/n) = (h*n)/(a*b) > 1, then you observe more co-occurrence than what to be expected by chance alone, assuming your sample is representative of the underlying population.

Alternatively, if (h*n)/(a*b) < 1, you observe less co-occurrence than expected by chance only.

(h*n)/(a*b) is the forbes' coefficient of association between two species.

It is a measure of association, not a formal test of association.